# How to show console output on webpage?

Tags: javascript, console, console.log, jsbin

When I go to websites like Codecademy or JSBin, I notice that they allow you to see console output. How does that work?

Just to clarify, let's say a user types this in a textbox

```
console.log('hello');
```

How can I make the output on the actual web page and just not the browser's console?

Comment: By adding it to a DOM object?

Comment: How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

As Shahar mentioned, the way to see the output on the actual web page is to add it into a DOM object. For example, if we create a div for the output and add output into it by using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<div id="output"><div>
```

Javascript, using jQuery:

```
// your example output
var string = "hello";

// append to end of output div
function outputToPage() {
    $('#output').append(string + "<br/>");
}
```

The above example would output `string` and line-break to the output div, whenever `outputToPage()` function is called. Please note that you need to have jQuery loaded for the jQuery's `.append()` method to work.

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase my question: How can I make it so that when a user types in console.log('hello'); , I will have a JavaScript interpreter read it and print it out to a webpage. What you have is just a string saying hello.

Comment: @idude is console.log(); the only method you want?